Why is the time complexity of nested loops O(n)
I was doing a Leetcode question "Longest Substring without Repeating Character" and came across this solution.
# use a set to keep track of letters and their index
    window = set()
    res = 0
    l = 0
    for r in range(len(s)):
        # remove letter until there is a dupe
        while s[r] in window:
            window.remove(s[l])
            l += 1

        # either its a new char or we got rid of dupe
        window.add(s[r])
        res = max(res, r-l+1)
            
    return res

The video said this was a O(n) time complexity program but I am confused how that can be. There is a conditional while loop inside the for loop so would that not be O(n^2). I am pretty new to Big O so I am confused how calculating time complexity works for nested loops in different situations.

The inner loop repetition count in this case is neither n nor a simple function of n. It changes all the time depending on input data. You need a different approach to assess the complexity. How about looking at window.remove(s[l]) and figuring how many times this can be called in total?

This is a standard sliding window solution. Note that each character is added to the window once and can be removed from the window at most once. Thus, the total number of iterations of the inner while loop does not exceed N (the number of characters in the string).
